# 6 topics, 3 questions on exam, only have to answer 1. what is the probability of a question ive revised coming up if i revise 2?

Tags: probability

So i have an exam and for the long answer bit there are 6 possible questions topics that will come up. the paper will only have 3 questions on it and im only expected to answer 1 of them, i know if i revise 4 of them then atleast 1 of them will definaly come up, but im feeling lazy, if i only revise 2 or 3 of the topics what is the probablily that atleast one of the topics ive revised will come up?

Comment: What do you mean by " question ive revised"?  Do you mean topics/questions you are studying?  Your question needs editing to be understandable.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty basic counting. There are ${6 \choose 3} = 20$ ways of choosing three questions out of six.

There are four questions that you haven't revised for. There are  ${4 \choose 3} = 4$ ways to pick a set of questions that don't contain anything you revised for.

Hence: there is a $4/20 = 1/5$ chance you only get questions you haven't revised for, or equivalently there's a $4/5$ chance you get at least one question that you have revised for.